# Como usar uma folha xml no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xml

Boa noite pessoal, sou novo em  criação de sites, fiz uma pagina em php que funciona bem usando um script para carregar dados de um arquivo XML.

Esse script carrega - um video, o titulo do video e a descrição cada vez que clique num link. A partir deste arquivo xml.

Porém quando subi no wordpress essa função não funciona, as DIVS ficam vazias como se ele não reconhece o XML, carregado pela função GET.

Gostaria de saber se tem como solucionar esse erro, agradeço.